# Restricting word list from within XSD Schema 1.1 (presumably using pattern?)

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I am modifying my XSD 1.1 Schema so particular words are not allowed to be entered in the corresponding element.

For example, in a simpletype I would like to error where the following characters have been input '/*' and '--' maybe even '&apos including ;'

I can't for the life of me figure out how to restrict multiple characters/words, does it even exist? I can easily restrict each character in turn whereas I want this to error 'My name /* is Craig' this is acceptable 'My name / is craig*'

Any help guys will be very much appreciated.

thanks
Craig

Answer (score 1):

I think this is quite hard to achieve with the pattern facet alone. Since you are using XSD 1.1 I would do it with an assertion facet

```
<xs:assertion test="
    not(contains($value, 'Trump')) and 
    not(contains($value, 'Clinton'))"/>
```

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for getting back to me. I am using XMLSpy 2015, and I don't seem to be able to insert the assertion type anywhere? It doesn't seem to be recongnised. My initial version is set to <?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?> - thanks

Comment: and the schema is set to version="1.1"

Comment: Altova claim to support XSD 1.1, but I've no idea how to switch it on. The XML declaration is irrelevant.